# Binary search slower, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, performance, list, intersection

EDIT: so it looks like this is normal behavior, so can anyone just recommend a faster way to do these numerous intersections?

so my problem is this. I have 8000 lists (strings in each list). For each list (ranging from size 50 to 400), I'm comparing it to every other list and performing a calculation based on the intersection number. So I'll do

list1(intersect)list1= number

list1(intersect)list2= number

list1(intersect)list888= number

And I do this for every list. Previously, I had HashList and my code was essentially this: (well, I was actually searching through properties of an object, so I
had to modify the code a bit, but it's basically this:

I have my two versions below, but if anyone knows anything faster, please let me know!

Loop through AllLists, getting each list, starting with list1, and then do this:

```
foreach (List list in AllLists)
{
    if (list1_length < list_length) //just a check to so I'm looping through the                  
                                    //smaller list
    {
        foreach (string word in list1)
        {
            if (block.generator_list.Contains(word))
            {
                //simple integer count
            }
        }
    }
// a little more code, but the same, but looping through the other list if it's smaller/bigger
```

Then I make the lists into regular lists, and applied Sort(), which changed my code to

```
foreach (List list in AllLists)
{
    if (list1_length < list_length) //just a check to so I'm looping through the                  
                                    //smaller list
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list1_length; i++)
        {
            var test = list.BinarySearch(list1[i]);
            if (test > -1)
            {
                //simple integer count
            }
        }
    }
```

The first version takes about 6 seconds, the other one takes more than 20 (I just stop there cuz otherwise it would take more than a minute!!!) (and this is for a smallish subset of the data)

I'm sure there's a drastic mistake somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: Where in that code are you sorting your lists? Or did you do it prior to this.

Comment: HashList is O(1) amortized, BinarySearch() is O(logN).  So this is completely normal.

Comment: Hi, yes, I did it prior to this

Comment: Really, so there's no other way to make it faster?

Comment: HashList is the way to go. Given you're doing about 8000 x 4000 list comparisons (if I understand correctly), so it's expected to take a while!

If you have a fixed list of strings it may be faster to iterate through all of these instead, but thinking about it, I think your method above would actually turn out to be faster. I can't think of other ways to speed it up unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have tried three distinct methods for achieving this (assuming I understood the problem correctly). Please note I have used `HashSet<int>` in order to more easily generate random input.
setting up:

```
List<HashSet<int>> allSets = new List<HashSet<int>>();
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 8000; ++i) {
    HashSet<int> ints = new HashSet<int>();
    for(int j = 0; j < rand.Next(50, 400); ++j) {
        ints.Add(rand.Next(0, 1000));
    }
    allSets.Add(ints);
}
```

the three methods I checked (code is what runs in the inner loop):

### the loop:

note that you are getting duplicated results in your code (intersecting set `A` with set `B` and later intersecting set `B` with set `A`).
It won't affect your performance thanks to the list length check you are doing. But iterating this way is clearer.

```
for(int i = 0; i < allSets.Count; ++i) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < allSets.Count; ++j) {

    }
}
```

### first method:

used `IEnumerable.Intersect()` to get the intersection with the other list and checked `IEnumerable.Count()` to get the size of the intersection.

```
var intersect = allSets[i].Intersect(allSets[j]);
count = intersect.Count();
```

this was the slowest one averaging 177s

### second method:

cloned the smaller set of the two sets I was intersecting, then used `ISet.IntersectWith()` and checked the resulting sets `Count`.

```
HashSet<int> intersect;
HashSet<int> intersectWith;
        if(allSets[i].Count < allSets[j].Count) {
            intersect = new HashSet<int>(allSets[i]);
            intersectWith = allSets[j];
        } else {
            intersect = new HashSet<int>(allSets[j]);
            intersectWith = allSets[i];
        }
        intersect.IntersectWith(intersectWith);
        count = intersect.Count;
    }
}
```

this one was slightly faster, averaging 154s

### third method:

did something very similar to what you did iterated over the shorter set and checked `ISet.Contains` on the longer set.

```
for(int i = 0; i < allSets.Count; ++i) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < allSets.Count; ++j) {
        count = 0;
        if(allSets[i].Count < allSets[j].Count) {
            loopingSet = allSets[i];
            containsSet = allSets[j];
        } else {
            loopingSet = allSets[j];
            containsSet = allSets[i];
        }
        foreach(int k in loopingSet) {
            if(containsSet.Contains(k)) {
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this method was by far the fastest (as expected), averaging 66s

### conclusion

the method you're using is the fastest of these three. I certainly can't think of a faster single threaded way to do this. Perhaps there is a better concurrent solution.

Comment: I'll try it, because my results were only for a small subset and it takes me like 8 minutes to do them all lol. Maybe because I'm not intersecting sets, but properties of objects that happen to be hashsets (and my sets are strings, but I don't think that matters much)? If I do parallel processing, where can I put the intersection numbers for each intersection? It seems if I do a matrix, I'll be accessing the same matrix, and that'll slow it down. What if I make an object with 3 properties, set1,set2, and intersection_number? Then ultimately I'll just have 64,000 instances of that object?

Comment: Is intersecting object properties slower than just taking those properties and making a set out of them (like your allsets) and intersecting those?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that one of the most important considerations in iterating/searching any kind of collection is to choose the collection type very carefully. To iterate through a normal collection for your purposes will not be the most optimal. Try using something like:

```
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>
```

Using the Contains() method while iterating over the shorter list of two (as you mentioned you're already doing) should give close to O(1) performance, the same as key lookups in the generic Dictionary type.

Comment: Wait, wasn't I using Hashsets already, or do you mean something different?

Comment: You were using the List<T> type

Comment: Yeah, I was using List<Hashset<string>>...? Can you clarify or show an example?

Comment: Ok, that you're already using HashSet was not shown in your code example or clear to me in your explanation. If you're already doing this, then you need to consider that comparing 8000 lists to each other is itself the bottleneck. You will not achieve optimum performance using a simple loop. Consider the System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel type to parallelize your calculations. Will post an example if I have time.

Comment: Thanks, I actually looked into that, and I implemented it without really understanding what I was doing, so I only gained a 3x speed improvement, but I'm not sure how to deal with the fact that I'm accessing the same variables at the same time, and that I'd like to store the intersection number somewhere. Right now, I think my inefficiency is causing out of memory exceptions halfway through (maybe also because my hashets consist of strings, not integers). Should I post my updated code in another question?

Comment: I don't think handling strings instead of ints will have any perceivable impact using HashSets. Using parallelism is a little tricky :-) There are many ways to slice and dice, including using the LINQ AsParallel() with various kinds of partitioners. There are also thread context considerations, which can hurt performance. No need to post your updated code... maybe you can explain, though, how you want to store the intersections.